# How to configure generic path `/nodejs` and `/main.js` path in Appium configuration

Tags: java, node.js, selenium, appium

I need to configure generic path instead of passing hard coded `/nodejs` and `/main.js` path in Appium configuration, like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" lib\server\main.js`

something like as below `System.getProperty(user.dir)+"src//test//resources//Config.txt";`

Comment: Can we configured /node.js path as environment variable and later used to initialized Appium server ?